# NISession() returns error - Apple Nearby Interactions

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, uikit, exc-bad-instruction

I have downloaded the Nearby Interactions project that Apple released [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/nearbyinteraction/implementing_interactions_between_users_in_close_proximity). When I try to run the application I get this error

[image]

I have not modified the original project and there is nothing in the ReadMe that details extra setup configuration. Only that certain devices can be used.
There are no logs to accompany this and so I'm not quite sure on the cause of this. I see others have been able to run the project and so wondering if anyone has any insight into this

Running on an iPhone 14 device

Also, as a side to this, if anyone has any example app they have built with Nearby Interactions but in SwiftUI I would love to see how you integrated it in.

Thanks!

Comment: Just downloaded and run on an iPhone 14 Pro, iOS 16.2 without any problem. Not that that is any help, I'm afraid!

Comment: However, I do get that crash on the simulator. Are you seeing it on an actual device?

Comment: Looks like this may be an iOS 16 issue… https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/722053

Comment: @AshleyMills yep, seems to be an iOS 16 issue when running on a simulator. 16.2 runs fine on a physical device. Thanks!